# Add a custom ascx template in the new files option

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I've searched for an answer to this, and I may not be phrasing it correctly but how do I add my own ascx template (or any file template) in the "add new item" of Visual Studio?

I have a set of `ascx` files, which inherit a custom class - This all works fine, however when I add a new `ascx`, I then have to go into the code behind and edit this to have the new inheritance plus a couple of other standard parts in the `page_load`.

Is there a way I can add my own `ascx` template which will have all this setup for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer can be found in the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tsyyf0yh.aspx) documentation:

To add a custom project item template to the Add New Item dialog box

> 1. Create or open a project in Visual Studio.
> 2. Add an item to the project and modify it if you want to.
> 3. Modify the code file to indicate where parameter replacement should take place. For more information, see How to: Substitute Parameters in
>      a Template.
> 4. On the File menu, click Export Template.
> 5. Click Item Template, select the project that contains the item, and click Next.
> 6. Select the item for which you want to create a template, and click Next.
> 7. Select the assembly references to include in the template, and click Next.
> 8. Type the icon file name, preview image, template name, and template description, and click Finish.
>
>    The files for the template are added to a .zip file and copied to the
>      `..\Users\username\Documents\Visual Studio
>      Version\Templates\ItemTemplates\` folder.

Comment: Thank you, I had searched high and low but to no avail - hence the question